# Formatting the month and year in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I want to display only the current month and year in my iPad app, as, 'November, 2012', for which I'm currently formatting the month to 'MMMM' and year to 'yyyy' and concatenating them. This works fine for most locales, however, not for the 'China' region.

My current code displays the month and year in 'China' region as,

[image]

However, this is isn't right. As it should be like it is displayed in the iOS calendar app,

[image]

Any Idea on how this can be achieved?

EDIT 1:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"MMMM";
NSString * monthString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] capitalizedString];
dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"yyyy";
NSString * yearString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] capitalizedString];

lblMonthAndYear.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",monthString,yearString];
```

Comment: Show the code that does formatting

Comment: Did you mean 'MMMM' instead of 'EEE' for getting "November"?

Comment: Try setting this, [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that your date formatter uses locale at all, the key here is to create a template using current locale, not just a format string, for example:

```
NSString *dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MMMM d"
                                                       options:0
                                                        locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat;
```

Comment: Perfect! Yes, that was the problem. Didn't know how to include the locale exactly here. Thanks for that lightspeed solution! @"MMMM yyyy" did the trick.